# Automated Update Of An Excel 2007 Table from a Centralized Data Repository (Excel Table)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have created and Excel 2007 based dynamic charting application that that charts various economic data.  The spreadsheet includes a Table that contains all the monthly economic data for about 25 different indices.   I would like to add a visual basic script that will enable the spreadsheet user (there will be many users using the same spreadsheet)  to push a button and have the visual basic script access a centralized data repository and update the economic data on the spreadsheet with new data in the central data repository.

The users will be on the same Wide Area Network and will likely need to update thier spreadsheet monthly. However, anytime a user does an update the update should fetch all the rows required to bring the particular spreadsheet up-to-data.

**My Question is. What's the best way to tackle this problem?**  Do excel Table have a query feature that would enable me to query the central repository with what amounts to a Select all sql statement and return all the rows or is there some other functionality that someone could suggest.

If someone can point me in the right direction, I think I can figure it out from there.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need your users to be able to update their data from the central repository, you don't even need code to do this. Use [Microsoft Query](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-HA010099664.aspx) to pull the data from the source (a sql database, MS Access, another Excel file, a web page, etc.). That establishes the data link. Then users can refresh the data on demand. You can even customize the data for each user by using parameters to filter the data based on selections in certain cells within the workbook.

Here are a few more links:

[MSDN Let's Get Connected in Excel 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545041%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

[Nick Hodge's Excel Blog » Excel 2007 - Getting External Data](http://excelusergroup.org/blogs/nickhodge/archive/2008/11/04/excel-2007-getting-external-data.aspx)

[Using parameters with web queries](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/WebQuery.asp)